# How to get tab url in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a tab with an external url. I want to to get the external url - not the tab url which is then redirected to the external url

I have tried:

```
    tab.FullUrl
    tab.Url
    tab.TabPath
```

All of these return the Tab url not the external url. Can anybody help me?

Edit

Sorry was a caching problem

```
     tab.Url
```

Works fine however you should use

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL().
It also could be used with the param tabID if your code isn't included in the desired tab (i.e. in a module or a skin object in the corresponding tab).